# Fatal: AggregateException encountered. remote: No anonymous write access. fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git, visual-studio, credentials

Not sure what has happened here but I was all up and running fine until today when I got these errors. I have tried to resolve it myself and seem to have gotten my self in deeper at not resolving the issues. I have removed my credentials like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCcrdW4Llm0&ab_channel=chinamatt) but as not resolved my issues and not sure what to try to do to get back working on projects.

It says to do this now but not got a clue what its going on about!

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for
```

as that is what the video above told me to do in the first place. I have tried to re-clone bit no matter which way in visual studio or Git bash I cannot get it to push to GitHub.

Everything was fine yesterday but I did notice an update in Visual Studio code which I was trying to avoid it updating but it did and now yet again locked out of my own accounts. I would setup GitHub with a Enabling two-factor authentication but with being a Diabetic is not a good thing to have a screen lock on so I have to avoid it at all cost.

Comment: I have got a little further on this issue and managed to get it to log into github but now getting these errors now. hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Comment: I tried a Git pull request but was rejected due to me trying else where to push upto github, which again I managed to do but not in a way I was expecting and it gave me another branch to confuse the matters

Comment: as or seemed to have workd but now getting a conflict  I have no clue on how to fix? This in Visual studio code? (Auto-merging docs/user-guide/TicWatch-Pro-3-side-load---xdrip.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in docs/user-guide/TicWatch-Pro-3-side-load---xdrip.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is clearly written in the error that from August 13 2021 git has been removed the access from the password so you have to use a private access token in place of password and to generate private access token go to the developer settings of the GitHub.